# Unexpected behavior of numpy.real_if_close compared to numpy.real, numpy.imag

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I am working my way through the [scipy tutorial](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/basic.html), and I encountered a behavior of the function numpy.real_if_close that I don't quite understand:

```
b = np.array([1+1j, 2+1j, 3+1j, 4+5e-15j])
b
>>>[1.+1.e+00j 2.+1.e+00j 3.+1.e+00j 4.+5.e-15j]

np.real(b)
>>>[1. 2. 3. 4.]
b.real
>>>[1. 2. 3. 4.]

np.imag(b)
>>>[0. 0. 0. 5.]
b.imag
>>>[0. 0. 0. 5.]

np.finfo(float).eps
>>>2.220446049250313e-16

b # <-- to make sure I didn't change b
>>>[1.+1.e+00j 2.+1.e+00j 3.+1.e+00j 4.+5.e-15j]

np.real_if_close(b, tol=1000) # <-- does not perform the approx 4+5e-14j ~= 4
>>>[1.+1.e+00j 2.+1.e+00j 3.+1.e+00j 4.+5.e-15j]
b.real_if_close(tol=1000) # <-- raises an AttributeError
>>>AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'real_if_close'

np.real_if_close([2.1 + 4e-14j], tol=1000) # <-- example from the tutorial
>>>[2.1]
```

From the documentation of [real_if_close](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.real_if_close.html#numpy.real_if_close), [real](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.real.html#numpy.real), and [imag](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.imag.html#numpy.imag) the parameters of the three functions are described the same way, therefore I am a little lost in their different behavior with respect to the same object.

- Am I assuming something wrong here?
- Is it an issue worth reporting?

Comment: Your output for `b.imag` does not look correct.  It should be `array([1.e+00, 1.e+00, 1.e+00, 5.e-15])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function `real_if_close` will only convert the array to real if *all* the elements have imaginary part close to zero.

Your `b.imag` is actually:

```
array([1.e+00, 1.e+00, 1.e+00, 5.e-15])
```

So the first three elements are 1, which are not close enough to zero...

If you repeat that with an array where all elements have imaginary part close to zero, it works as expected:

```
b = np.array([1+0j, 2+1e-14j, 3-1e-15j, 4+5e-15j])
```

And `np.real_if_close(b, tol=1000)` returns:

```
array([1., 2., 3., 4.])
```